What makes the difference between the Mean Absolute Deviation (AAD) and Standard Deviation of a distrubution constant?
We can see very nicely in the normal distribution that the relationship between the mean absolute deviation and standard deviation is a constant ratio (by sqrt(2/pi)). What is it that gives a distribution the characteristic of having a constant ratio between these two measures? Is it symmetry?
The motivation of this question is that, hearing that the mean absolute deviation was more robust and less sensitive to outliers than the standard deviation (sure one is always less, but if it's always the same scale then that's not really "handling" outliers), it didn't make as much sense to me if the relationship is always a constant ratio, therefore it must not hold true for all distributions. Thus, I'm curious, how can we tell for other distributions that the difference between between the standard deviation and mean absolute deviation is just a constant ratio? Is it ever not just a constant ratio?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation

What exactly do you mean with "constant"?

Do you mean "mean absolute deviation" or "median absolute deviation"? The latter is a much more common measure.

@Kenny, you probably mean (sorry I did not get that immediately) that the ratio of the two measures is constant across a (linear?) transformation. Is that indeed what you mean? That would be simple to show I think, looking at the formula's in the link you mentioned.

Is expectation of a random variable constant? I think that would answer your query.

Your "factor difference" appears to be a ratio.  The ratio of any two statistics that are scale-covariant will be scale-invariant.  Consequently, a (trivial) answer is that this ratio will be constant in any scale family of distributions.  One can construct examples of distribution families that are not scale families but still have this property -- is that what you're looking for?

Yes a constant ratio is exactly what I meant thank you! If I understand correctly - the ratio will be constant if a distribution belongs to a "scale" family? I am intrigued by your last point though - I thought this constant ratio is a result of being in a "scale" family distribution, but it can also exist in non scale families? Apologies in advance, I'll work on making my math vocabulary more precise.

A follow up question is that, isn't it the case that there isn't much value in terms of handling outliers for the mean absolute deviation versus standard deviation if the difference is always just a constant ratio? It seems like people have been using the mean absolute deviation over the standard deviation with the intention that it is somehow more capable for handling outliers, and this would only make sense to me if for some distributions it is not a constant ratio difference and somehow as more outliers are included, the ratio would be increased to "normalize" the outliers.

If the followup is what you really want to ask, then you should ask that instead.  But generally, you can construct families of distributions with fixed ratios.  All you need is to perturb any chosen distribution smoothly in a way that does not change its MAD or its SD. That introduces two constraints on an infinite set of possible perturbations, usually leaving quite a lot of available examples ;-).
